# Do sadhaka aware of siddhi for all mantras?

Tags: mantras, siddhi

Assume that a sadhaka got mantra siddhi for a mantra.

Do sadhaka aware of his siddhi for all mantras in hinduism? or are there  mantras such that sadhaka does't able to decide whether he/she attained siddhi over the mantra?